# How do I show the data retrieved from Firebase onto a view controller that is inside a tab bar controller?

Tags: swift, firebase, storyboard

I have a ViewController that I would like to show the activity indicator while fetching username data from firebase and changing the username on the MenuViewController. After that, it would show the MenuViewController. But the problem I'm facing is the "menuVC.greetText = "Hi " + username" line doesn't work. There is no username being shown on the ViewController. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
class LoadingViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    startLoading {
        switchToMenu()
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


func startLoading(finished: () -> Void) {
    
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    
    authenticateUserAndConfigureView()
    
    finished()
    
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    
}

func switchToMenu() {
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let mainViewController  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MainVC")
    self.view.window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
    
    self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
     
    }
    
}

func authenticateUserAndConfigureView() {

    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loginController  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "LoginViewController")
        self.view.window?.rootViewController = loginController
        
        self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
         
        }
    }
    else {
        //let tabBar = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabBar  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MainVC") as! UITabBarController
        let menuVC = tabBar.viewControllers?[0] as! MenuViewController
            
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
            
        Database.database().reference().child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let username = value?["Username"] as? String ?? ""
            menuVC.greetText = "Hi " + username
            }
            )
            
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with `asynchronous` function here and you are also inside `closure`, so meaning that as soon as you leave the closure, the assigned values inside closure will not be available. You need `completionHandler` to deal with it. You can make a separate function of it and then call it inside `authenticateUserAndConfigureView`.

```
func getName(completion:@escaping((String)->()) {
     Database.database().reference().child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let username = value?["Username"] as? String ?? ""
            completion(name)
          }
```

And then you can call this function like this.

```
getName{(nameOfUser) in
     print("Name is \(nameOfUser)")
  }
```

In your case:

Calling inside `authenticateUserAndConfigureView`

```
func authenticateUserAndConfigureView() {
if (......) {
  //All your code
}
else {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabBar  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MainVC") as! UITabBarController
        let menuVC = tabBar.viewControllers?[0] as! MenuViewController
            self.getName{(name) in
            menuVC.greetText = "Hi" + name       
     }
     
  }

}
```

You may need to use `DispatchQueue` here for possible `timing` issue, but I am not sure about that. If you do, let me know.